# ¿Por qué no me salen los estilos CSS en Github pages?

Tags: css, github, github-pages, stylus

Realice un ejercicio de frontend mentor y lo quise publicar en GitHub pages para publicar la solución en la página de frontend mentor. El ejercicio lo realice con Stylus y para compilar utilice prepros. El problema que se me presento es que cuando abro la página no me cargan los estilos ¿Alguien sabe porque pasa eso? Agradezco la ayuda.
Página: https://dcuevas24.github.io/Profile-card-component-main/
Repositorio: https://github.com/dcuevas24/Profile-card-component-main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si miras  en el explorador en las herramientas de dev en la parte de network (red) podrias verificar que el error es que no encuentra por el path (error HTTP)

Si ves intenta cargar un archivo desde

*https://dcuevas24.github.io/CSS/main.css*

Y deberia ser desde esta ubicacion

*https://dcuevas24.github.io/Profile-card-component-main/CSS/main.css*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es porque colocaste la referencia al css relativo al raiz de aplicacion. deberias colocarlo relativo a la pagina

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!